# Multi decision engine for increasing OCR accuracy

Tags: ocr

I want to be able to compare the results i get from running an OCR on the same document three times.  Are there any tools out there that i can use to make this happen?

I would like compare the three documents and based on what characters are the same 3/3 times or 2/3 times, create a fourth document with the output of this decision.  I am using Abby Fine reader which has given me great results, but i am trying to do everything i can to get to 100%.

I know microsoft word has a "compare documents" function, and i would like to be able to do this type of analysis on a larger scale with a robust algorithm.

any ideas?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

If the output is a simple text file, you could use the bash `diff` command and a simple shell script to compare them. You could probably then use a slightly more complicated shell script to parse through the output file and create a final document.